# Jquery Sending a Method to a Function "Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'each'"

Tags: jquery, methods, foreach, draggable, droppable

I am having an issue trying to create a re-useable function for setting up elements as either draggable or droppable.

Creating 2 separate functions for this works:

```
makedroppable($('.empty_child_article_image'), handleChildDropEvent);
```

or

```
makedraggable($('.empty_related_article_image'), handleAlternativeDragEvent);


function makedroppable(droppableClass, specificHandler){   
  droppableClass.droppable( {
    drop: specificHandler,
    hoverClass: 'hovered'
  });  
};
```

or

```
function makedraggable(droppableClass, specificHandler){   
      droppableClass.draggable( {
        drop: specificHandler,
        hoverClass: 'hovered'
      });  
    };
```

This however does not work:

```
makedroppable($('.empty_child_article_image').droppable, handleChildDropEvent);

    function makedroppable(dragordrop_func, specificHandler) {
       dragordrop_func({
       drop: function(){specificHandler.apply($ ,specificHandler)},
       hoverClass: 'hovered',
     }); 
    }
```

And I get an error for "dragordrop_func({" with this error in my console

> Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'each'

I have tried a number of other solutions and from what i've read this should work. What am I doing wrong?

Any help or guidance is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` object reference is lost when you pass `$('.empty_child_article_image').droppable` as an argument to the function. Inside `function makedroppable` -> `this` will be the window object and not your `$('.empty_child_article_image')` object.

And so the error is thrown because the `this` object points to `window` object and not the `$('.empty_child_article_image')` inside droppable function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to ensure that it passes it correctly? Or force it too?

Comment: As some further help for people I did make it work in a slightly more ugly way. This being to send droppable as a string and then wrap it in square brackets.
    makedroppable($('.empty_child_article_image'), "droppable" , handleChildDropEvent);

      function makedroppable(selector, dragordrop, specificHandler) {
    $(selector)[dragordrop]({
        drop: dropFunction,
        accept: '.ui-draggable',
        hoverClass: 'hovered'
)}
    }

Comment: @user1166885 - you lose the context when you pass it as an argument. The draggable has tb be called as $('.empty_child_article_image').draggable.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your knowlegde and time SKS